# android manifest.xml,editor with text editor is ok,but using android manifest editor not working

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I'm new to android,as I followed the "Hello World" lesson using Eclipse,curious things happened:when I opened the manifest.xml file with "Android Manifest Editor" and typed some codes in it,such as permission codes,it caused wrong:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

In this sentence:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

said these:" tag should specify a target API level (the highest verified version; when running on later versions, compatibility behaviors may be 
 enabled) with android:targetSdkVersion="?""

But if I used "Text Editor" to editor it ,then it was ok...I don't know why,anyone knows about that?Thanks.

Comment: `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include a `targetSdkVersion` attribute so that the app knows what version you are targeting:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

(Or another version if you are creating an app with backwards compatibility or similar)

The reason you see a warning or error message is because the Manifest editor is more advanced and specialized for editing android manifests compared to the default text editor that can't recognize these problems.

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about my problem,when I used Text Editor I can correctly run the program,but using Android manifest editor it can't run properly,so I don't know why.But after I add what you said in Android manifest editor it can run properly:)That's odd.

Comment: @user1448979 I see. Maybe you have some setting that prevents you from compiling the app with warnings? Anyway, you should add the target version attribute (as it is good practice) and see if that works :)